# Java: Android: MediaPlayer sometimes returning null onResume

Tags: java, android, media-player, onresume

I'm trying to get music to play on my app but I've hit a problem which I can't figure out. When I first load the program, it works fine and the music loads and plays. If I let the phone idle and then come back to it, the app works again. But the third time I let it idle and return, the mediaplayer will return a null and crash the app on resuming. Here is the code for the mediaplayer:

```
    public void startMusic(Context context)
{           
    if (music != null){
        if (music.isPlaying()){
            music.stop();
        }
        music.release();
        music = null;
    }

    music = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.song);

    music.setLooping(true);
    musicPlaying = true;   
}
```

The app will crash when it hits the `music.setLooping(true);` line of code, saying that music is null.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the logcat output. There should be an exception in the MediaPlayer class that will give you a hint about why the creation failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was releasing the music in the wrong place. I was doing it in the view, when I should have been doing it in the activity.